# Listen for pop-up and close it using windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, wsh

I have the following batch file used to close a time-out pop up window (with the title "Information") when it shows, so that I do not get logged out of a system. However, if the pop-up window is not showing, the sendkeys command is applied to the active window (e.g. a Microsoft Word or Internet Explorer that I am working on), which isn't my intended outcome. How do I listen for the pop-up and apply the sendkeys command only when the pop-up is active?

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    cls
    color 0a
    :loop
        %SendKeys% "{TAB}{TAB} "
        timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul
    goto :loop

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.AppActivate("Information");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: I would think you could do something like: `if wshShell.AppActivate("Information") = true then.....`

Comment: @Squashman where do I put that line?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    cls
    color 0a
    :loop
        %SendKeys% "{TAB}{TAB} "
        timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul
    goto :loop

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
if (WshShell.AppActivate("Information")) {
      WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stop the process that is related to that popup with:

```
taskkill /IM "program.exe" /F
```

If you want to stop the process each certain period of time, execute the code above in a batch script with the help of a windows schedule task.